# year is seen twice although i do not write

Tags: bibtex, article

[image]

```
@Article{38survey,
  author={Ahuja, Sanjay P and Mani, Sindhu and Zambrano, Jesus},
  year={2012},
  title={A survey of the state of cloud computing in healthcare},
  journal={Network and Communication Technologies},
  volume={1},
  number={2},
  pages={p12}

}
```

I am writing exactly like this but somehow in reference list year is seen twice. What is the reason?

Comment: Hi and welcome, we need a bit [more information](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html). The bibliography style or biblatex-style handle the data from the database. The database entry alone doesn't give any clue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As @Johannes_B suggested, please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551) How do you cite that entry? Could you provide a document that we could compile?

Comment: I cite it with \cite{38survey} like this.

Comment: Please follow the link in my first comment and add the MWE to the question. The edit button is on the left of your name  ;-)

Comment: @Bukulu, be careful during the edition to avoid losing the previous one.

Comment: What can be the reason? It writes 2 times :(

Comment: Without knowing which bibliography style you are using, it is impossible to say.  For standard styles, this is not the usual behaviour.

Comment: My bibliography style is acmsmall  @AndrewSwann

Comment: Looking at the acmsmall sample document this seems to be standard behaviour for article entries.  The second year will have a month and day added if the appropriate data is given.

Comment: I think the *document class*, not the bibliography style, you're using is called `acmsmall`. The associated bibliography stye should be `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals`.

Comment: yes! that is my style @Mico

Comment: Can you send me the link? I could not find @AndrewSwann

Comment: By the way, the contents of the `pages` field are incorrect. I believe they should be `"12-19"` rather than `"p12"`.

Comment: The sample is in the v2-acmsmall.zip file at http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/

Answer (score 5):

The appearance of your bibliography is determined by this command:

`\bibliographystyle{style-name}`

You can preview a brief list of author-year bibliography styles [here](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/ALPHA/bibstylescompared.pdf):

As Mico identified, your current bibliography style is `ACM-Reference-Format-Journals`, and it gives this output:

[image: ACM-Reference-Format-Journals bibliography style]

The year is listed twice, but this appears to be a property of the bibliography style, not an error.

If you wanted to list the year just once, you could use (for example) `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` and get this result:

[image: plainnat bibliography style]

But if you are preparing to submit a paper with the `acmsmall` class, you should leave the settings as they are.